# Are all integers kept in 2's complement form in all microprocessors?

Tags: computer-architecture

Are all integers kept in 2's complement form in all microprocessors or do microprocessors use 1's complement form and unsigned integer form too?

Comment: There is no advantage to using 1's complement, so one would assume that this method isn't used. Floating point numbers use a different approach – a sign bit.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Thank you very much for your answer, I've changed the domain to integers only since the question was a little bit nonsense, now could you please answer again?

Comment: My answer stands, though there is really no way to know what happens in all microprocessors, especially historical ones.

Comment: Some ClearPath Dorado hardware is (I think) still being used though Unisys is no longer making new processors, instead relying on emulation on x86. [This StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/161797/2467198) from 23 May 2017 asks "Is one's complement a real-world issue, or just a historical one?" (Since the Dorado emulation presents one's complement to application software, it is still a real-world issue in a limited context.)

Answer (score 2):

If there was the keyword "almost" attached to the question then answering it could have been much more easy. As people have mentioned in the comments that nothing can be said with certainty about "all" the processors but yes majority of them do.

2s compliment is definitely preferable over the 1s compliment as it provides you a better range for instance if you have 8 bits the you can represent numbers in the range -2^7 to 2^7-1 with it (1 bit being for the signed bit). its interpretation also is easy and quick for the processors.

However for floating point numbers most processors use a different strategy to save them efficiently. This post would fall short if I needed to explain about them but matter of fact they don't use 2s compliment they rather have the concept of exponential, mantissa and signed bit. And there are 2 commonly used variant of these known as the single precision and double precision floating point representation which are technically same and vary only by the range they can represent. If you want to read further about this you can visit https://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/coding/ieeefloat.html (not my website, but the website explains the whole thing fabulously).

Let me know if I could help you further in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

All integers in all microprocessors, that is a lot of integers in a lot of microprocessors!

Not all microprocessors are CPUs. There are a lot of special-purpose processors in a lot of weird niches. It is not inconceivable that one of those will have a perfectly good reason to use some other representation than two's complement.

Historically, there have been a lot of weird architectures. I'm not sure if any ever used one's complement or explicit signs, but there were certainly ones that didn't even use binary! Decimal representation was not uncommon in the early days. Some Russian computers apparently used ternary.

Even if we ignore ancient history and special-purpose processors, there is still heavy usage of binary coded decimals in the mainframe and midrange area. E.g. IBM's z Processors, and some CPUs in the POWER line have support for binary coded decimals.

Comment: I don't understand how it answers the question.

Comment: The question asks whether all integers in all microprocessors are stored in two's complement. So, if you can find only one single instance in the entire history of computing where someone used anything other than two's complement to store an integer, then the answer is "No". I gave several such examples: at least some integers on IBM mainframes are stored in BCD.